# Template Driven Form doesn't show correct value

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a bug when I remove an address and add a new one. The previous address gets overwritten with the new one.

I created a small demo application to showcase my problem:

github: https://github.com/kolomu/HeroDemo
stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gitter-5o6ydi

It's not that the model is wrong, somehow the view which angular renders isn't in updated correctly.

View:

```
  <form #heroForm="ngForm">

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="addresses" *ngFor="let address of model.addresses; let i=index">
        <label for="address-{{i}}">Address {{i}}</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="address.location" name="location-{{i}}">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="remove(address)">Remove Address</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="add()">Add Address</button>

  </form>
```

Component Class:

```
export class HeroFormComponent {

  model = new Hero(18, 'Dr IQ', [new Address(1,'main','Earth'), new Address(9001,'sub','Moon')]);

  remove(address) {
    const index = this.model.addresses.findIndex(
      address => address.id === address.id
    );

    this.model.addresses.splice(index, 1);
  }

  add(){
    this.model.addresses.push(new Address());
  }

}
```

Data Model:

```
export class Address {
    constructor(public id?: number, public type?:string, public location?: string) { }
}


export class Hero {

    constructor(
      public id: number,
      public name: string,
      public addresses: Address[]
    ) {  }

}
```

GIF-Image showcasing the problem:
https://gfycat.com/DelightfulSpiffyBetafish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that you use the same name `address` for the parameter of the `remove` method and for the parameter in `findIndex`. As a result, the comparison `address.id === address.id` returns `true` for the first item tested because it compares the item to itself.

```
remove(address) {
  const index = this.model.addresses.findIndex(
    address => address.id === address.id          <-- Always true!
  );
  ...
}
```

You should use a different name, for example `_address` for the parameter in `findIndex` (as shown in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gitter-m2qg6n)):

```
remove(address) {
  const index = this.model.addresses.findIndex(
    _address => _address.id === address.id
  );
  ...
}
```

Or you could pass the index as a parameter to `remove`, [as suggested by Embrioka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47847284/1009922).

---

In your code sample, when you add a new address after deleting the first one, the two fields show the same data (the value of the new address). That is strange, since everything looks fine in the template and in the code. According to my tests, the problem comes from the fact that the name of the new input element is the same as the one used previously for the other element. In your template, if you replace:

```
name="location-{{i}}"
```

with

```
name="location-{{address.id}}"
```

the problem disappears, as long as each `address.id` is unique. Apparently, reusing the same name for a different item prevents the input content from being updated correctly by Angular.

Comment: Thanks for that advice however the problem remains. If you try to add an address after you removed the first one, the second one will get wiped.

Comment: The problem seems to come from the name of the input element. If you change `name="location-{{i}}"` for `name="location-{{address.id}}`, it works (as long as the `address.id` are different, I assume). I updated [my stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gitter-m2qg6n). I don't know why reusing the same name for a different item prevents Angular from updating the content however.

Answer (score 1):

Do not pass the whole address, only the index:

```
<div class="form-group">
      <div class="addresses" *ngFor="let address of model.addresses; let i=index">
        <label for="address-{{i}}">Address {{i}}</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="address.location" name="location-{{i}}">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="remove(i)">Remove Address</button>
      </div>
</div>
```

And in the ts:

```
remove(index) {
    this.model.addresses.splice(index, 1);
}
```

With this solution you don't even have to find the index.

The problem with your solution what the previous commenter mentioned and also you id will be undefined, so in the add method just define an ID or pick an another property when looking for the index!

Comment: thanks for that advice but this still don't fixes the main issue.

Comment: Kev, the problem is what I mentioned. Your ID won't be defined. What you can do is to calculate the biggest id in your array and create a new address every time with that id.

Comment: I tried to add a new address like so (for demo purposes) :
add(){
    this.model.addresses.push(new Address(3,'test'));
  }

Even with the provided index and the remove method you mentioned it won't fix the display bug.

Comment: ahh okey, I see your problem. Actually that's a pretty weird behavior.